# How do you set the Google chrome date format to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss?

Tags: google-chrome, date-time

My system datetime format is set to ISO 8601, but since I am using British English in Chrome, Chome is insisting I use dd/mm/yyyy. How do I switch to the correct format?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome ignores the settings at the Windows level. A workaround I use is to set either Chrome, or my web app (if I can access such settings) to a country that **does** use the ISO-8601 format. For example, Canada (en-CA). It's not perfect, but at least the dates in my web app in Chrome match my Windows clock.

Answer (score 0):

The date format in Chrome is derived from the language.

This is set in Chrome three-points menu :
*Settings > Advanced > Languages*.

Use the "Add language" button to choose another variant of English
that corresponds to your date preference.

Comment: @Ramhound: I meant Chrome's Settings. I better worded the answer. Changing the Windows language will also work (without setting it in Chrome).

Comment: Except Chrome doesn't seem to have any predefined English variant that supports ISO-8601. :(

Comment: @LennartL: You can set the date to whatever you like : YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD. If for your local region Windows forces you to pick from a list, it's possible to choose whatever format you want through the old *Control Panel > Region > Additional Settings... > Date*.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm on a Mac, not Windows. Either way, I've already set up myself up to have the YYYY-MM-DD format apply globally on my system. The problem is that Chrome doesn't pay attention to this, presumably because JavaScript can only handle single locale strings of the form en-US. Chrome itself gives you the choice of several different English locales, but none of them sadly come with a YYYY-MM-DD date format. It's really too bad, because there is at least one that does it right -- en-SE [English (Sweden)], but Chrome doesn't include that as an option.

Comment: I have the same problem in Ubuntu, system's locale are ignored by Chrome browser and the browser itself has nothing regarding locale, but language options...

Comment: @tymik: I think this merits a separate question.

Comment: @harrymc why? I assume people would like to know that this solution works only with Windows. And inconsistency of Chrome's behaviour across different OSes is not obvious in the first place. Mind that I'm not asking for a solution here - so far I believe there is none apart from filling a bug report to Chrome